# Ruby gem equivalent of PERL storable

Tags: ruby, storable

Does Ruby have a gem equivalent of PERL's Storable?
I have tried rcstorable, but it only reads, it does not save.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PStore, maybe that's what you are looking for.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html

It's in the Stdlib, so no gem is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the equivalent of Storable's freeze and thaw using `Marshal`:

In Perl:

```
use Storable;

my $serialised_data = freeze( $data_ref );

# and later

my $data_ref = thaw( $serialised_data );
```

In Ruby:

```
serialised_data = Marshal.dump( object );

# and later

object = Marshal.load( serialised_data );
```

One big difference - `Storable` covers more Perl library objects "out of the box" than Ruby's `Marshal` does, for non-core objects in Ruby sometimes you may need to add support for Marshal yourself. All the basic types - numbers, strings, arrays, hashes - work just fine though.